# Best Search Engine Optimized Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to create a wordpress based site for programming articles, blogs, videos etc. Basically a kind of learning portal for newbies and experienced programmers.

Can someone please suggest best wordpress themes which are search engine optimized for google adsense and can be modified to host custom advertisement banners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all wordpress themes nowadays are SEO friendly but the one that i've used and that suites your need well is **Swift**. Swift because it is very fast loading, has lots of configuration options, placeholder for adsense code.

Also look for **Saffusion** theme if you want more fine-grain control and customization options.
But it is bit heavy.